# Creating new plugin for webservice

Tags: android, json, wordpress, plugins

I wrote this code to connect to a database, make some queries and send them by `json` like `web api`.

I want to create plugin that will work like a WEB API. Then upload it on WP modules on internet and people may install them on their sites to connect my android App. Anywhere.

This is my `php` code (include db_connect and sending json and respond to my Android App)

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_REQUEST ['id']))
        echo "id is not set";
    if (isset ( $_REQUEST ['id'] )) {
        $id = $_REQUEST ['id'];
        $response = array ();
        mysql_connect('localhost','db_admin','password') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('db_name') or die(mysql_error());
        $sql= "select * from employee";
        $run=mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows ($run) > 0) {
            while ($row=  mysql_fetch_array($run)){
                $product = array ();
                $product ["id"] = $row [0];
                $product ["name"] = $row [1];
                $product ["salary"] = $row [2];
                $response [] = $product;
            }
            echo  json_encode ( $response );
        }
    }
?>
```

My manager wants me not to use the default `Woocommerse WORDPRESS API`,so I have to create new plugin. and want to know how can I convert it to standard module?

Is it possible at all ?

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I will created like this:
First off would create handler for the request, either via ajax (im not sure if this way is supported in android ) like this;

```
function get_some_information(){
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    if(!isset($user_id) || empty($user_id)){
       return json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Empty Request'
       ]);
    }
    $data = get_info_from_data($user_id);
    if(!empty($data)){
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;

    }else{
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Error while processing data'
        ]);
        exit;
    }

}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_some_information', 'get_some_information'); //for auth users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_some_information', '_get_some_information' ); //for the rest
```

Note: there is an `exit;` you always need to terminate the application to be able to get the json, otherwise the output it will be 0
With this now we have an access point to data and validation; and it looks a bit more clean.

```
function get_some_information($id){
  $result = [];
  // do all things and added to the array

  return $result;
}
```